# useQuery renders when state changes

Tags: react-native, react-query

I want to useQuery renders whenever the state changes
is there any option in useQuery hook

```
`export const Search = ({ navigation }) => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState();
const [dismiss, setDismiss] = useState(false);
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState();

const searchHander = (query) => {
    setSearch(query)
    setDismiss(true)
}

const searching = useQuery(['searching', search], () => api.search(search));

useMemo(() => {
    setSearchResult(searching?.data ? searching?.data?.results : []);
}, [searching?.data])

const searchResults = ({ item }) => {
    return <View style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}><SearchResults navigation={navigation} data={item} /></View>
}

const desmiss = useRef(null);

return (...)}`
```

useQuery is not depend to state

Comment: you can use `refetch`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question:

> I want to useQuery renders whenever the state changes

I'm just assuming you want to `refetch` when the state changes, because when state changes, your component *does* render.

For this, all you need to do is add `search` to the queryKey, which you have already done.

Further, I can see that you are calling `setSearchResults` in `useMemo` which is a) unnecessary because react-query already gives you the result and b) violates component purity because you call setState during render.

I think the component should just be:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState();
const [dismiss, setDismiss] = useState(false);
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState();

const searchHander = (query) => {
    setSearch(query)
    setDismiss(true)
}

const searching = useQuery(['searching', search], () => api.search(search));
const searchResult = searching?.data?.results ?? []
```

Then you can work with `searchResult`, and whenever `setSearch` is called, your query will refetch.